# mySQL java union

Tags: java, mysql, union

i used this query java and mysql but its not work (if i send directly mysql console its work bun in java not work.)

Here down is my code:

```
PreparedStatement pst;
ResultSet rs;
String Sql6 ="(SELECT a,b,c  FROM T1 where a not in(0)  ORDER BY a desc LIMIT 5)  
              UNION   
              (SELECT e,f,g FROM T2 where e not in(0) ORDER BY e desc LIMIT 5)";

pst = this.getC().prepareStatement(sql6);
System.out.println(    "===========2"); //its work this line
rs = pst.executeQuery();
System.out.println(    "===========3"); //its not work this line
```

Where is the problem?

thank you

Comment: Please clarify what is the problem. Sorry, I didn't understand your question. What do you mean by `i used this query java and mysql but its not work (if i send directly mysql console its work bun in java not work.)`

Comment: Where is connection object?

Comment: Using IN() or NOT IN() with just one value is very bad style, you should in your case write != 0 instead of NOT IN(0)

Comment: i tried !=0  and i tried out of where clause but its not work. like this
SELECT a,b,c  FROM T1   ORDER BY a desc LIMIT 5  
              UNION   
              SELECT e,f,g FROM T2   ORDER BY e desc LIMIT 5

Comment: Testing the SQL statement I get: `ORDER BY clause should come after UNION not before`

Comment: no @franck  my code  work on mysql console but its not work in java. wyh?

Comment: @asisiyah Catch the exception and print the stack trace. `try { rs = pst.executeQuery(); } (SQLException e) { System.err.println(e.getMessage()); }`

Comment: @asisiyah I agree that the following SQL code runs on MySQL: `CREATE TABLE T1(a INT PRIMARY KEY, b INT, c INT); 
CREATE TABLE T2(e INT PRIMARY KEY, f INT, g INT); 
INSERT INTO T1(a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3); 
INSERT INTO T2(e,f,g) VALUES(3,4,5); 
(SELECT a,b,c FROM T1 where a not in(0) ORDER BY a desc LIMIT 5)
UNION 
(SELECT e,f,g FROM T2 where e not in(0) ORDER BY e desc LIMIT 5); ` Now where is your problem with your Java application? Is a connection to your db successfully established? Is there an error message?

Comment: i havent error message. if i send only one query its okey but when i was use union its not work in netbeans with java, i try in mysql console with union its work , but when i was run in java netbeans it not work

Answer (score 0):

if you use UNION in java jdbc , you attention to outcome. out come data column is only first  column name

```
(SELECT t1id,t1name,t1type FROM t1 ORDER BY t1id desc limit 5)  
UNION
(SELECT t2id,t2color,t2place FROM t2 ORDER BY t2id  desc LIMIT 5)
```

outcome are
`t1id ->(t1id & t2id)  t1name ->(t1name & t2color)  t1type -> (t1type & t2place)`
... both of select one list

its work in java jdbc.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: its answer, i made mistake that i think outcome all colum names, but outcome are only first column names